# I'm trying to understand this circuit and how to implement it onto a bread board

Tags: circuit-analysis, current

I'm a beginner and I would like to better understand this circuit diagram and have it implemented onto a breadboard. All the diagrams I've been expose to have batteries so I can tell which is the positive and negative side but for this specific diagram, there is a 15V rather than a battery symbol. How do I know which was is negative and which way is positive? Also, How would I implement this diagram onto a breadboard? Any starting points, tips, and explanations on how to do this would be amazing!
[image: Piezo circuit]

Comment: Welcome! "15V" is +15 V. Ground symbol is "negative". 113 kHz is possible on a breadboard, but I would highly recommend you first simulate and understand the circuit, then draw it in for example KiCad and lay out your own PCB for it instead with proper ground plane.

Comment: That's quite an ambitious circuit to get started with @ac23... if you want to learn more about how a circuit with the 555 Timer IC works and how to lay such a circuit out on a breadboard, then perhaps have a look at (for example) https://circuitdigest.com/555-timer-circuits

Comment: Thanks, what is the significance of the green and red highlights?

Comment: The highlights appear to be something added by "Fritzing",

Answer (score 6):

> I'm a beginner

We all are, at some moment in time.

> I would like to better understand this circuit diagram

Perhaps one of the more important practices to get into, as a segue to a continuing education for understanding a circuit, or building it, is to learn to re-draw. The goals of understanding are different from the goals of building something. So re-drawing skills for understanding are different from the re-drawing skills needed for making it. All this puts a huge emphasis on just getting down and learning to re-draw schematics, generally. This is a skill set you will learn to value over time.

Let's start with a stripped down version of the schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fec3NZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is now broken up into two parts. There's a important named connection being shared, **OUT**. Clearly, **OUT** has an important role. But although when constructing this wires will be needed to connect them back up, in the schematic shown I've removed those connection wires. The reason is that the wire itself easily gets in the way of understanding the circuit. So it is often better to dump some of the wiring.

You could take this to extremes and have no wires at all and just place labels everywhere. But that ***also*** would get in the way of understanding a circuit. So somewhere in between these two extremes is a better place to be.

How to know where to begin and end? Well, certain parts of a schematic perform certain functions. And within such a function, there is a high degree of inter-connection. Between one such function and another different function, there tends to be only one wire or maybe two or three that are important, so that these functions communicate to each other over a sparse few wires.

Leave the wiring within a highly inter-connected functional block, since knowing how all that is connected is usually important to know about. But then label and remove wires between functions. This lets you isolate functional blocks, so that you can study them individually without getting distracted wondering if the wire between them is tangled up in some complex way (usually that is not true and just gets in the way.) Also, such few wires between function blocks will have a single and important meaning and are easily labeled well.

*(Above, note that I also removed \$C_4\$, which, while helpful, adds nothing to your understanding at this point.)*

Let's get back to that **OUT** pin. From the 555 timer IC it goes two places. One of them is actually part of the same function block -- the 555 timer -- but goes to an RC circuit branch. Perhaps I should have left a wire there? There is a good argument to have done so because, literally, the connection between the **OUT** pin of the 555 and the RC branch is part-and-parcel with the 555 timer IC functional block (an astable oscillator block.)

So, let's add the wire back:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYvU7J.png)</sup>

Each functional block can be examined by itself, keeping in mind that there is a labeled connection between them. These could be put onto separate pieces of paper, in fact, and looked at in isolation.

This is the divide-and-conquer approach and it's important to learn how to navigate through it. Whether or not the first schematic above is better than the second can be a matter of taste. An argument for the first one is that the RC branch is a *thing of its own* -- it sets the timing. So it could be extracted out as a separate function block:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3E8h2.png)</sup>

And here, you can see that there is some kind of *feedback* going on, where the output of the middle function block goes *backwards* towards the input of the first function block (RC timer), whose output feeds the input of the middle function block. This arrangement emphasizes this fundamental nature.

How you choose to break things up should be driven by what you want to communicate to others. That is, once you become a writer rather than a reader of circuits. As a reader, you are just learning. So you need to practice a lot to gain some skill at this.

The elephant in the room is the 555 timer. It would now help if you had a block diagram of the 555 timer in front of you. You really do need it for a fuller understanding. Just from a quick search, I picked this one from [here](https://envirementalb.com/555-timer-ic):

[image]

Let's get down to business.

Note that there are three resistors in series within the 555 at the top. These form a *resistor divider* (you need to learn about these if you don't already know about them.) In this case, the middle connection points between resistors will be at 1/3rd and at 2/3rds of Vcc, as indicated.

Note also that these points are also connected to two triangles labeled **1** and **2**. These triangles also have input wires that go over to pins 2 and 6. Take note of that. If we wire 2 and 6 together, then both these triangles will be comparing 1/3rd and at 2/3rds of Vcc with the same external voltage point. It's very common to connect pins 2 and 6 together on a 555. So common that it almost should have been built into the device. But leaving them open allows for some added freedom for people with creative imaginations. So they did, as there was no harm since it's very easy to connect them back up outside the 555.

Note that the RC timer's output (midpoint along the branch) is connected to the 555's tied pin 2/6 wiring. This means both those triangle comparators will be checking the voltage across the capacitor against 1/3rd and at 2/3rds of Vcc. When the voltage rises above 2/3rds, then the output will be driven LOW (comparator **2** will make the flip-flop's **R** [reset] become active.) This causes the \$\overline{Q}\$ output to go HIGH. That turns on the NPN shown near the upper left corner, but it also feeds into the Output Driver (which inverts this signal to a LOW) that then drives pin 3 to LOW.

When **OUT** is LOW, this goes back to the RC timer section and pulls down on the resistor, causing the capacitor voltage to now move downwards towards increasingly lower voltages. This moves it away from 2/3rds Vcc and towards ground. The capacitor makes this a slow process. But it happens. Eventually, the voltage falls below 1/3rd Vcc and comparator **1** makes the flip-flop's **S** [set] become active. This causes the \$\overline{Q}\$ output to go LOW. That turns the NPN off and feeds the inverting Output Driver that then drives pin 3 to HIGH.

Once **OUT** is back HIGH, the resistor pulls up on the capacitor voltage, which now rises, again.

It's that process that causes the 555 timer to act as an astable multivibrator and *oscillate*. But the values of R and C in the RC timer determine how long each half-cycle takes and therefore the frequency.

That completes an understanding of everything but the last function block -- the piezo driver.

This is just an open-drain driver that when active (**OUT** is HIGH) pulls down on the inductor and the capacitor at once. This pulling down on the capacitor causes a sudden change in the voltage across the piezo, which responds. Meanwhile, the voltage difference across the inductor causes the current in the inductor to rise. And the capacitor discharges, too.

At some point **OUT** goes LOW and turns the NFET off. When that happens, the inductor refuses to instantly stop its current, so it instead immediately reverses the sign of the voltage across itself (the NFET drain lead literally ***flies*** to a high positive voltage.) That causes, yet again, a sudden change of the voltage across the piezo (via the capacitor), while also the now-declining inductor current charges the capacitor.

*(\$R_2\$ was added for a subtle reason that would take more than I want to say right now. You could use a value 10 times larger and be fine. You could remove it by shorting it and still be fine. But the circuit is a little better with it than without it.)*

Thus, the astable multivibrator drives the piezo.

One final note -- a return to the schematic again. Let's make one more modification:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foWLlw.png)</sup>

I've removed the labels and restored the wires. The only labels left are for the positive power lead (Vcc is the same as +) and the negative power lead (inverted down-pointing triangle at bottom is the same as -). But the function blocks remain highlighted.